# When a Warlock Invocation lets me cast a spell, do I also have to make it one of my Spells Known?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, eldritch-invocations, spellcasting

My friends and I are going to be starting another campaign in the near future. I've going to be playing as a Warlock and I was hoping to get some clarification on the use of the Eldritch Invocation feature of the class.

Some of the invocations allow you cast spells. One instance is Armor of Shadows, whose text reads

> You can cast *mage armor* on yourself at will, without expanding a spell slot or material components.

Does this indicate that Mage Armor has to be one of the spells you know (in other words, count against the spells known for your level?) Or is this considered something separate from normal spellcasting for Warlocks?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## No

No feature which grants new spells counts against your spells known, unless it explicitly says so. Spells Known for the Warlock is exclusively for the Pact Magic mechanic, which this is not a part of.