# If I have the Armor of Shadows Eldritch Invocation, do I know the Mage Armor spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, eldritch-invocations, spellcasting

The warlock's [Eldritch Invocation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388) "Armor of Shadows" says:

> You can cast *mage armor* on yourself at will, without expending a spell slot or material components.

Does this mean I know the spell? That is, can I cast it on someone else by expending a spell slot and material component as normal?

Comment: Related but distinct: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59056/when-a-warlock-invocation-lets-me-cast-a-spell-do-i-also-have-to-make-it-one-of

Comment: How is the linked question distinct?

Comment: I'm not asking if it's one of my spells known. I'm asking if since the invocation gives me the ability to cast it without it being a spell known if I'm able to cast it on someone else by more traditional means without having to learn it through traditional means. @András

Comment: Just realized I did originally ask "Does this mean I know the spell?". That may not be my best wording and it's certainly not the focus of the question. The focus of it was "can I cast it on someone else by expending a spell slot and material component as normal?"

Comment: this is a distinction without a difference.

Comment: I still don't see how this is a duplicate though. I'm specifically asking if I can cast the spell on someone else by using a spell slot and material component. That is not at all addressed in the "duplicate" question. @András

Comment: ___How___ could you cast it on someone else, if it is not a known spell?

Comment: @András my thought was since it gives me the ability to cast it on myself without the components maybe it could let me cast it on someone else *with* components

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## No, the spell is not a known spell on your list

The invocation merely grants you the ability to cast it at will - but it is not considered one of your 'spells known'. The language you quote simply states that you may cast it at will. But the qualifier you also quote remains:

> cast *mage armor* on yourself

That is the only way you can cast it - but you can cast it at will. This is very helpful in cases of *dispel magic* or other means that may end the spell before you'd like it to end. It also doesn't use up a spell slot to maintain your *mage armor*, which is a huge benefit - especially with the limited slots a Warlock has.

Comment: That's what I thought but I wanted to be sure. Thanks for the clarification!